# Using one date variable between two SELECT statements with INNER JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, database, group-by, inner-join

I have a table with columns such as: date, name of the employee, shift's number (1,2 or 3). I would like to aggregate data to receive number of shifts for a specific employee based on selected date (that means to this specified date). I need to see columns such as: date, name of the employee, shift's number (1,2 or 3), shifts total to the date specifed in the first column.

Using INNER JOIN with two SELECT statements I am able to get total number of shifts for all dates, e.g. (shift 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees a
INNER JOIN (SELECT employee, COUNT(value) AS shifts FROM employees WHERE value='1' GROUP BY employee) b ON b.employee=a.employee
WHERE date>='2020-11-05'
```

How could I change my query to show only the sum of shifts for each employee until selected date?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Sample data as requested, what I have:

```
   date      employee   value
2020-11-05       X        1
2020-11-05       Y        2
2020-11-05       Z        3
2020-11-06       X        1
2020-11-06       Y        2
2020-11-06       Z        3
```

What I need:

```
   date      employee   value   shifts_1
2020-11-05       X        1        1
2020-11-05       Y        2        0
2020-11-05       Z        3        0
2020-11-06       X        1        2
2020-11-06       Y        2        0
2020-11-06       Z        3        0
```

To sum up, in this case, the last column should show number of first shifts that were assigned to each employee until specified date.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, b.SumOfShifts, b.shifts
FROM employees a
INNER JOIN (SELECT employee, COUNT(value) AS shifts, SUM(value) as SumOfShifts FROM employees WHERE value='1' GROUP BY employee) b ON b.employee=a.employee
WHERE date>='2020-11-05'

Comment: 'Value' specifies which shift was assigned to the employee on a given date so the result of the query is unfortunately: "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator."

Comment: OH - I understood the problem wrong. Did you try: SET iValue = CAST(ValueAS int)

Comment: Hmm, after casting value as int and using the exact query from your answer I get two columns (shifts and SumOfShifts) with identical values which are the sum of all the first shifts for each employee, but this value is constant regardless of specified date.

Comment: SELECT *, b.shifts FROM employees a INNER JOIN (SELECT employee, COUNT((CAST(value  AS int))) AS shifts FROM employees WHERE value='1' GROUP BY employee) b ON b.employee=a.employee WHERE date>='2020-11-05'.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives a similar result, I get sum of all the first shifts (total number of) regardless of the specified date.